# Unable to compile Kotlin project with osmdroid 6.1.13

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, osmdroid

After creating a Kotlin project in Androidstudio following the tutorial on your Wiki (https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library-(Kotlin)) I'm not able to compile the project. The error message I get:

FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android' ):6.1.13.
Required by:
project :app > org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.13
project :app > org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.13
```

### Environment

Linux, Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 2, Gradle plugin 7.2.2, Gradle version 7.5.1

Source code of project can be found here: https://gitlab.com/brmmm3/btmap

build.gradle in **app**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.greatreset.btmap"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.1'

    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.13'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.13'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.13'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.13'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

gradle build output shows:

```
...
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug FAILED
Watching 24 directories to track changes
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android'%20)/6.1.13/osmdroid-android'%20)-6.1.13.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android'%20)/6.1.13/osmdroid-android'%20)-6.1.13.pom]
:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.219 secs.
Resolve mutations for :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug (Thread[included builds,5,main]) started.
Resolve mutations for :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug (Thread[included builds,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
...
```

What can be seen is that gradle is adding `%20)` to the download path. Where does gradle get this from?

Comment: Can you update your question with implementation of osmdroid from build.gradle?

Comment: Is https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1831 your issue report? Well, we have to wait for OsmDroid maintainer(s) to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the pom files for wms and mapsforge are buggy for versions 6.1.13 and 6.1.12. The discussion can be found here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1831
In the meantime using 6.1.11 solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Propblem was in pom-file:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1831#issuecomment-1221915903

Fixed in version 6.1.14:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/milestone/25